# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error on loading jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, validation

I'm making a web application where I need to validate fields. The .js is loading but it gives the Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error at line 2 `$("#adduser-form").validate({`. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Following is my validation file code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#adduser-form").validate({
        rules : {
            email : {
                required : true,
                email : true,
                maxlength : 64
            },
            firstname : {
                required : true,
                minlength : 3,
                maxlength : 32
            },
            lastname : {
                maxlength : 32,
                minlength : 3,
                required : true
            },
            password : {
                maxlength : 32,
                minlength : 8,
                required : true
            },
            company : {
                maxlength : 64,
                minlength : 3,
                required : false
            },
            title : {
                maxlength : 64,
                minlength : 3,
                required : false
            }
        },

        messages : {

            email: { 
                required: "Email is required.",
                email: "Please enter a valid Email address."
            }, 
            firstname: { 
                required:"First Name is required."
            }, 
            lastname: { 
                required:"Last Name is required."
            },
            password: { 
                required:"Password is required.",
            }, 

        },
        invalidHandler : function(event, validator) {//display error alert on form submit
            $('.alert-error', $('#adduser-form')).show();
        },

        highlight : function(element) {// hightlight error inputs
            $(element).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
            // set error class to the control group
        },

        success : function(label) {
            label.closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            label.remove();
        },

        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            error.addClass('help-small no-left-padding').insertAfter(element.closest('.input-icon'));
        },

        submitHandler : function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

    $('#adduser-form input').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            if ($('#adduser-form').validate().form()) {
                $('#adduser-form').submit();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Did you load the plugin?

Comment: If you are using the jQuery validation library, you have to include that library.  The Documentation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: either the js file is not loading, or element with id `adduser-form` does not exist

Comment: As a matter of fact, I was missing the jQuery validation library. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't include the jQuery validation library. I included it and it worked like a charm!